# How to git clone a repository to heroku

Tags: git, heroku

I have a git repository called `first-blog` and it contains a `python-django` project named as `myproject`. I tried to clone this repository to heroku using the command

```
$ git clone https://github.com/heroku/first-blog.git
```

I got an error

```
Cloning into 'first-blog'...
Username for 'https://github.com': AparnaBalagopal
Password for 'https://AparnaBalagopal@github.com': 
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/heroku/first-blog.git/' not found
```

How can I solve this error?

Comment: You may be mixed up here.  What is the name of your *local* project, and where in *your* GitHub remote repository does it exist?  You're currently trying to clone a project from Heroku's repository which doesn't exist.  We can talk about deploying it to Heroku later.

Comment: how can I clone a git repository to heroku?

Answer (score 1):

Your repository is at

```
https://github.com/AparnaBalagopal/first-blog.git
```

I'm not sure how you got the original link, but your repos will always be at

```
https://github.com/<your_username>/<repo_name>.git
```

Your links points to a repo for the user 'Heroku'.